# Phantom mysql_error from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql statement that runs fine when I run it in phpmyadmin, but kicks up an incredibly ambiguous server `mysql_error`  when I run it from PHP:

> > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> >     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> >     near '
>
> ```
> UPDATE srSignals SET falseBreak = "true",'
> ```
>
> at line 5

Full sql statement(s):

```
UPDATE srSignals
                SET falseBreak = "true",
                    candleClose = 1.51132,
                    result=-48
                WHERE id=4429;UPDATE srSignals
                SET falseBreak = "true",
                    candleClose = 1.51132,
                    result=-27
                WHERE id=4431;
```

Anyone know what is wrong with this statement, or why it is working when copied/pasted in phpmyadmin but not through a PHP request?

Comment: btw, column 'falsebreak' is a string, the rest are ints

Comment: However, `mysql_` functions are deprecated from long time ago!

Comment: @fabio - it's like being asked to give up a pair of scissors because they want me to use a swiss army knife for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.
You have to use single quotes not doublequotes like tis:

```
            UPDATE srSignals
            SET falseBreak = 'true',
                candleClose = 1.51132,
                result=-48
            WHERE id=4429;UPDATE srSignals
            SET falseBreak = 'true',
                candleClose = 1.51132,
                result=-27
            WHERE id=4431;
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on ';' and execute two sql statements.